# subgit fails with 'svn: E204900: File <filename> doesn't exist but should'

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I'm migrating a big SVN repository (11K revisions and lots of big files).

After resuming several times due to communication problems, it started to fail with this message:

> SubGit version 3.2.5 ('Bobique') build #3694
>
> Translating Subversion revisions to Git commits...
>
> INSTALLATION FAILED
>
> error: svn: E204900: File  doesn't exist but should
>   error: File MCCResources.properties doesn't exist but should
>   error: Unexpected error has occurred; please report along with the logs ('\subgit-install-20170812-164015.zip')
>   error:   to http://issues.tmatesoft.com/, thank you!

When I read the logs, I found the exact file and revision subgit is complaining about. As there's no evident SVN working copy, I tried to see if the file is missing from SVN repo at the given revision. It is there! I even checked the diff and it is totally fine.

This error is not allowing me to continue with the migration and I don't want to restart it unless I can guarantee that it won't fail, it took 1 week to get to this point (26%).

Comment: As SubGit developer, I would recommend you to file an issue at http://issues.tmatesoft.com as the error message says, because at the moment there's no enough information to solve it. When the issue is resolved, I or you will post the answer here.

Comment: What other information do you need in order to solve this problem?

Comment: `svn log -v SVN_URL` output would also be useful. And it's good to find at which revision SVN and Git histories started to diverge (e.g. Git doesn't contain that file while SVN does or vice versa). To do that you need to see revision numbers for Git commits. You can do that after setting up you Git client as it is recommended in "Recommended client-side Git configuration" chapter of [SubGit book](https://subgit.com/remote-book.html). But better open an issue in the tracker to start discussion.